# Unsupported operating system Laravel 8 with Sail on Windows 10 (WSL2)

Tags: linux, docker, windows-10, wsl-2, laravel-sail

I've spent 13 hours to compose Laravel Sail and I hadn't able to install it on Windows 10 operating system.
But later fortunately my collegaue found the solution when he also bumbed into this error message:

```
Unsupported operating system [MINGW64_NT-10.0-19042]. Laravel Sail supports macOS, Linux, and Windows (WSL2).
```

During the 13 hours:

- Firstly I installed the Docker Desktop to Windows what runs the Docker environment.
- Docker requires WSL-2 on Windows and it seemed to me also needs installed Linux operation system. That's why I did this whole process: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and I installed Ubuntu 20.04 version.
- After the installation I copy my whole project into the folder of Linux user. Bud I coudn't do anything in it (for example pull or push to my git repository) because of authentication issues.
- To solve this problem I created a symlink between the project in Windows and Linux based on these two answers: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545505/how-to-synchronize-code-files-on-windows-with-wsl-linux/62715180#62715180](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62715180/10473070), [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227492/laravel-8-laravel-sail-for-dev-on-windows-10-is-slow-how-to-speed-up/65236920#65236920](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65236920/10473070)
- It didn't solve the problem that's why I deleted the `/vendor/` folder in my project and ran `composer udpate` based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65513584/10473070 Also didn't work.
- After I did all the next process without success: https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-laravel-sail-with-the-docker-desktop-wsl-2-backend-3768a126a85
- It was a side effect that the MySQL couldn't reach the remote database and when the Docker finally worked the process consume half of my available memory.
- My final try was to create an empty Laravel 8 project for testing with curl call by this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows
- The result was failure. Finally I uninstalled Linux and Docker Desktop.

The solution and partial explanations are in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is in Sail and the issue is a kind of bug.

But first the prepare steps:

- You need install Docker Desktop on your Windos
- You need install and set WSL 2 by this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install but
- You absolutely **not** need to install Linux on Windows. Because the problem is an operation system checking condition in Sail.
- Find the `sail` file in the vendor folder: `vendor/laravel/sail/bin/sail` and change from this code:

```
     Verify operating system is supported...
    case "${UNAMEOUT}" in
        Linux*)             MACHINE=linux;;
        Darwin*)            MACHINE=mac;;
        *)                  MACHINE="UNKNOWN"
    esac
    
    if [ "$MACHINE" == "UNKNOWN" ]; then
        echo "Unsupported operating system [$(uname -s)]. Laravel Sail supports macOS, Linux, and Windows (WSL2)." >&2
    
        exit 1
    fi
```

to this:

```
    # Verify operating system is supported...
    #case "${UNAMEOUT}" in
    #    Linux*)             MACHINE=linux;;
    #    Darwin*)            MACHINE=mac;;
    #    *)                  MACHINE="UNKNOWN"
    #esac
    #
    #if [ "$MACHINE" == "UNKNOWN" ]; then
    #    echo "Unsupported operating system [$(uname -s)]. Laravel Sail supports macOS, Linux, and Windows (WSL2)." >&2
    #
    #    exit 1
    #fi
```

This solve the problem.
And why can we do this?
Because to check the `vendor/laravel/sail/bin/sail` bash file you can notice that every command can run in bash and terminal on Windows also without any problem.
Maybe they forget to put a Windows checking line in this code segment above.

To do these process Laravel Sail works like a charm based on Laravel Sail documentation.

And don't forget that this is just a hotfix because the next Sail update will override the modified sail bash file!

Comment: Wow, what a ridiculous way to run docker :S what's this Sail good for again?